# In javascript, how can I check to see if a textarea has only one line worth of text?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I would like to make a different behavior for a textarea if textarea has more than one line worth of text.

However, by default, if I make a textarea, text area has enough height for 2 rows to begin with even without any contents.

I do not want that.

How can I check to see if I have single line in a textarea or not with javascript?

Comment: A single line for the *value*, or for the *height*? A newly created textarea will not have any characters, it'll be empty

Comment: should have been clear. for the height please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery: `$("#myTextarea").rows`

vanilla JS: `document.getElementById("myTextarea").rows`